# Cannot install Subversive SVN Team Provider

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

When I try to install the Subversive SVN Team Provider from the Eclipse Marketplace (or from their project site), I get the following error:

`The following solutions are not available: Subversive - SVN Team Provider 2.0 Proceed with the installation anyways?`

Is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: what version of Eclipse were you using @Willem de Wit ?

Comment: Note: Even in Photon (2018) the way with the use of the Eclipse Marketplace does not work.

Comment: It is a dead project: https://jaxenter.com/eclipse-photon-wayne-beaton-interview-146150.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I worked around the issue by installing the plugin via the following steps:

1. Go to 'Help >> Install New Software'
2. Enter the Luna software repository URL: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/
3. Search for SVN

This way the installation succeeds.

Comment: Among other things, this means the Eclipse modularity framework is not as advanced as people claim it to be.

Comment: I just had the same issue as this (I am using Eclipse Photon) and got around it by using this solution and changing the release name from luna to oxygen which was the preceding version

Answer (score 3):

I just continued with installation and then go to:
window>preferences>team
now click on "svn" menu and then choose "SVN conector" tab, click "Get connectors" button and choose latest SVN Kit or whatever

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble downloading (even with the "Install New Software" solution from Willem de Wit), adding

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

after

```
-vmargs
```

in your `eclipse.ini` might help. It did help me with Eclipse Neon.

Comment: I have Eclipse neon, but this solution doesn't work for me