# Eclipse Checkstyle - The following solutions are not available checkstyle plug-in 7.3.0

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle, eclipse-marketplace

I can't install checkstyle I keep getting

`The following solutions are not available checkstyle plug-in 7.3.0`

The same with other plugins too.

Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> SearchBox (checkstyle) -> then I recieve

`The following solutions are not available: Checkstyle Plug-in 7.3.0 (id=net.sf.eclipsecs.feature.group, site=http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/update/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the plugin offline and manually put that plugins to your Eclipse: https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-cs/

Hope this help.

Comment: I ended up doing this. Unfortunately what happened also happened for subversive. So I don't know why its broken stuff.

Comment: @Mark: I'm not sure. But with Subversive, I don't have any issues. It seems the network has issue. Do you use proxy or not?

Comment: No I don't use a proxy. [Here's same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203954/cannot-install-subversive-svn-team-provider)